# How to disable CsrfPreventionFilter in Camunda 7.17?

Tags: spring-boot, camunda, camunda-modeler, camunda-plugin

I have upgraded the camunda to 7.17 and I noticed that the CsrfPreventionFilter is now been added to the servlet context. How can I disable it?
I am using Camunda 7.17.0 and Spring boot 2.6.7

Thanks